# Invoke-Command from powershell v3 to powershell v2

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have 2 systems. One of them has PowerShell version 2 and the other has PowerShell version 3. I used Invoke-command from system has version 3 to system has version 2. My output isn't correct. When I use my command in system with PowerShell 2 locally my output has 200 rows but in remotely has 150 rows. Why does it happen?

```
$log | ForEach-Object{
    get-eventlog -log  $_ -After $yesterday -Before $todaye |
        Group-Object EventID, EntryType, Source, MachineName,
            {(([String]$_.TimeGenerated) -split " ")[0]},
            {(([String]$_.TimeGenerated) -split " ")[1]} -NoElement |
        Select-Object count, name |
        ForEach-Object {
            $properties = @{
                'ServerName' = ($_.Name -split ", ")[3];
                'day'        = (($_.Name -split ", ")[4] -split " ")[0];
                'time'       = (($_.Name -split ", ")[5]);
                'EventID'    = ($_.Name -split ", ")[0];
                'EventType'  = ($_.Name -split ", ")[1];
                'Source'     = ($_.Name -split ", ")[2];
                'Count'      = $_.Count;
            }
            $psobject = new-object psobject -Property $properties
            $csv += $psobject
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you use? What happens when you execute the code locally in PS2 and PS3? Do you still get different results?

Comment: When I execute code locally in PS2 and PS3 I get true result. but when I execute code from PS3 remotlly to PS2 I get wrong result.When I execute my code in PS2 I get 200 rows in my result but where thsame code execute in PS3 remotlly to PS2 I get 150 rows in my result.

Comment: It's impossible to try and troubleshoot without seeing the code and results. Can you replicate the issue with code you can post in your question?

Comment: Where do `$log` and `$csv` come from? What does your `Invoke-Command` statement look like? What kind of records are missing from the remote result?